# Converting overlapped outlines into a single line

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am trying to make a animal logo with golden ratio. As it is my first try with golden ratio I am having a problem & I am working on illustrator.

[image]

Problem: Basically it looks like a single outline in the fox. In few shapes I overlapped the outlines. Now it became hard to manipulate the outlines. I need a single outline. Is there any way to convert the outline into a single outline.

Hope you understood my problem . Thank you.

Comment: Select all > Join ?

Comment: is that possible? I thought more that two point doesn't work on joining .

Comment: Could you leave out both the animal logo and the golden ratio, and describe your actual problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Individual shapes require individual paths. You can't "merge" the paths of two separate shapes so they "share" a common path.

Overlapping paths is how it's done in any vector application.

If you want single paths internally, then you would essentially need to draw things as an outline of the *entire*, overall, shape, then bisecting paths internally. However, then you would have one shape with lines on it, as opposed to separate shapes capable of a separate color fills.

There are shortcuts though. For example...

- If there are filled shapes, they can be stacked to *overlap areas*. So, paths don't necessarily need to line up with one another.
- Or, after creation Illustrator's Pathfinder Panel can be used to reduce overlapping shapes down to perfectly aligned separate objects without the need to manually align anything.

Comment: I was also thinking the same way. Now I know what to do. Thank you very much for the **shortcuts**.